# Creating a Marimekko chart with python

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I was trying to make a Marimekko chart, but encountered a problem.

My codes are looking like this.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

artist1 = [22.99, 29.77, 32.75, 31.62, 33.52]
artist2 = [21.59, 23.51, 28.62, 21.9, 26.96]
artist3 = [19.82, 17.83, 13.79, 19.7, 18.6]
artist4 = [18.0, 17.01, 12.87, 14.57, 12.6]
artist5 = [17.6, 11.87, 11.98, 12.21, 8.32]
genre_list = ['Pop', 'R&B/Hip Hop', 'Dance/Electronic', 'Rock', 'Latin']
genre_proportion = [40.96, 23.61, 18.53, 13.43, 3.47]


labels = genre_list
widths = np.array(genre_proportion)

data = {
    "1": artist5,
    "2": artist4,
    "3": artist3,
    "4": artist2,
    "5": artist1
}

fig = go.Figure()
for key in data:
    fig.add_trace(
      go.Bar(
        name=key,
        y=data[key],
        x=np.cumsum(widths)-widths,
        width=widths,
        offset=0
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Marimekko Chart",
    barmode="stack"
)

fig.show
```

And my graph came out like this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os49U.png)

The bars are overlapping on top of each other, rather than stacking up. How should I fix this?

Comment: I ran your code in my environment. The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqbR4.png) is as follows. My environment is plotly:5.18.0